# Can I keep normal browser navigation in Blazor (reload new page when clicking an anchor A)?

Tags: html, blazor, anchor, blazor-webassembly

What I want is similar to [`ForceLoad` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#navigation-options) but for the entire page. Or in other word, Blazor should not modify behavior of the page anchor `a` elements.

> ForceLoad: Bypass client-side routing and force the browser to load the new page from the server, whether or not the URI is handled by the client-side router. The default value is false.

```
Navigation.NavigateTo("/path", new NavigationOptions
{
    HistoryEntryState = "Navigation state"
});
```

I am making a "hybrid" website (**NOT** hybrid app) that is served by a normal ASP.NET Core and inside one of the pages, there's a Blazor app. However when user clicks a normal link, the new page is not loaded and Blazor try to navigate instead.

Is there any option so that Blazor would not intervene with the page anchor `a` elements? So that when user click a link, they are redirected to that page normally.

Comment: A kind of hacky way is adding this to your <a> tags: 'onclick="event.stopPropagation()"'

Comment: Why can't you use `ForceLoad`?  It goes back to the server to reload whatever Url you have requested.  The server responds based on its HttpRequest pipeline.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis hi, the Blazor app doesn't even see those links. It's served by the host ASP.NET Core website. Basically, A serves a normal ASP.NET Core website with content, including a `<div id="app">...</div>` for Blazor app B. But now all the links served by A stops working as well because B intercepts them.

Comment: Take a look at these two CodeProject articles which should help you configure your server correctly for serving both Blazor and non-Blazor pages - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5321697/Building-a-Blazor-Server-Application-from-the-Web  and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5299017/Building-a-Blazor-WASM-and-Server-All-In-One-Solut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LocationChanged` event of `NavigationManager`, I can manually intercept and then redirect (`NavigateTo`) with `forceLoad` option. You can put the event handler anywhere but for my case I put it in the `App.razor`:

```cs
@inject NavigationManager Nav;

// ...

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Nav.LocationChanged += (_, e) =>
        {
            Nav.NavigateTo(e.Location, true);
        };
    }
}
```